# Why do these parameters not work?

Tags: c#, nullable, out

```
public static string ChangeDeviceState(int deviceID, DeviceState nextState)
{
    bool temp1;
    string temp = "";
    return ChangeDeviceState(deviceID, nextState, temp1, temp, "", "", "", "", ""); 
}

public static string ChangeDeviceState(int deviceID, DeviceState nextState, out bool? isAccessToken, out String challengeOrToken, string accessToken, string serialNumber, string MACAddress, string deviceModel, string answer )
{
```

All I'm trying to do is have another method where the other parameters aren't necessary. I The bool isAccessToken has to be nullable, and challengeOrToken has to be an out param.

I'm getting an illegal arguments error.

I really don't understand these parameter features in c#. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't including [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) in your parameter call when required and `temp1` is not a [nullable boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (`bool?`).

```
public static string ChangeDeviceState(int deviceID, DeviceState nextState)
{
    bool? temp1;
    string temp;
    return ChangeDeviceState(deviceID, nextState, out temp1, out temp, "", "", "", "", ""); 
}
```